# Sending mail with task parallel library throws error

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0

CODE:-

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var item in arr)//arr contains 1000+ mailids
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    using (MailMessage msg = new MailMessage())
                        {
                            msg=getmsg();//p-shadow code no erorr here
                            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                            smtp.Host = smtpServer;
                            smtp.Port = smtpPort;
                            smtp.EnableSsl = isSmtpSsl != 0 ? true : false;
                            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUName,smtpPass);
                            smtp.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
                            smtp.Send(msg);//---throws error....
                            //sql code to insert db that mail is send
                        }
                }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray<Task>());
```

ERROR-"Failure sending mail."

INTERNAL ERROR-"Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."

Comment: Could it be that you're opening too many connections to the SMTP server, or hitting it too fast and it's throttling you? What happens if you do one per second ... or one every five seconds?

Comment: I don't think `SmtpClient` (or servers) supports multiple connections to the same server at the same time.  Think about what you're asking it to do: you're asking multiple `SmtpClient` objects to connect to the *same* server and send an email.  `SmtpClient` will re-use connections to the same server, so you're likely in a race condition.  Have you tried using `SendAsync` instead of using a `Task`?

Comment: At the very least, I would expect you'd want to use one `SmtpClient` object

Comment: I had the same sort of project to do last week. Will post some code as soon as i get to a pc. P.S use a parallel for loop instead of creating multiple tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the exception 'net_io_connectionclosed', please look at this link as it might point you in the right direction about why the connection is being closed. It could be authentication problems, firewall etc.

[Enabling Tracing for System.Net](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/feroze_daud/archive/2005/05/12/416922.aspx)

Please find below the code that I would use in your situation instead of spawning 1000 tasks which is not very efficient.

[Sending bulk emails with Tasks Parallel.ForEach](http://talkdotnet.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/sending-bulk-emails-with-tasks-parallel-foreach/)

Comment: thanks for the solution..i want to ask how u decide const int _clientcount=15?
is clientcount depend on runing hardware or number of smtp per machine is limited by .net/iis

Comment: That's just for my environment. Depends on each environment and the setup of your SMTP server. It might only allow say 5 connections per IP. Maybe use a config setting so you can adjust it per environment.

Comment: @RyanGunn where you set up SMTPCLients i have a need to change it to have it for different hosts. as i would have emails getting sent using different host smtp credentials. So i would have to spin up 15 clients for different host. can you please give me an example on how i can do it

Answer (score 0):

As Jim mentions, you're likely just hitting a throttling/rejection situation.  IMHO, you're likely to be more successful by 1) using a single SmtpClient rather than N of them (so the single client could internally serialize as/if necessary) and 2) using the built-in async call ([SendMailAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193996.aspx)) instead of StartNew and calling the sync version.

Something like:

```
var messages = ... // get collection of MailMessage instances
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient { ... }; // construct a single SmtpClient
var tasks = messages.Select(smtpClient.SendMailAsync).ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

I'm not sure if that's really going to help much, though - if it still fails, you might just need to make a single long-running Task that sends the emails serially.

Comment: If there is an e-mail transmission in progress and you call SendAsync or Send again, you will receive an InvalidOperationException. Taken from "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx"

Comment: @DNNDev.co.za - the method my code snippet calls is SendMailAsync, not Send nor SendAsync.  Of course, it might behave the same way and the docs just weren't updated, but that bit of doc doesn't say it'll fail :)

Comment: Apologies, I miss read what your code was doing and thought it was calling SendAsync.